# Hot reload for spring boot backend + frontend

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I rode those docs about spring dev tools and hot reload

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-exclude

And according to that is see there is such posibility to hot reload java and backed React/Typescript/webpack app

This is our architecture (in shortcut)

```
mainmodule
    backendModules <- those modules are just maven project have theirs poms and etc
          backendModule1
          backendModule2
fontendModule
       content <- React/Typescript/Webpack/Less etc
```

backendModule2 - We are using to start backend
backendModule1 - is just some additional services
fontendModule/content - is our whole react app

Am I right if I say to have reload for our frontend files I have to:

1. Configure Intellij as I'm doing it normally for backend <- this is easy

   1a. Change registry

   1b. select build project automatically

My question is what I have to do to force reloading of frontend files - So developer just need to run 1 app and then backend + frontend will be reloaded automaticlly

2. Add frontend extensions to resource patterns(Intellij: Build, execution -> compiler)? jsx, json, js, less and etc?
3. According to doc add "spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths"

Did anyone was able to do that? We are not getting any errors and etc...

Let me know if something seems to be unclear so we can clarify that

Comment: Launching in debug mode will be your best bet in eclipse/intellij. Note that if you change any frontend assets the developer will need to force a reload of the page. It's also not feasible to change allot of things at run-time and will require a restart.

Comment: @Oskar how are you serving your static frontend content?

Comment: There are probably several solutions. What I do is I have a spring boot backend with dev-tools so I can reload it easily from Intellij. For the Angular frontend I just use angular cli with development server and proxy configured to redirect my requests to the port that the backend is running on. This was I use what is given out of the box for both frontend and backend without any additional hacks. I am not sure if such a solution will be feasible for you.

Answer (score 10):

I know of 2 different ways that work to do that.

1) Using Intellij File Watcher Plugin

2) Running webpack dev server as a reverse proxy for your spring-boot app

---

1)

- Install Plugin "File Watchers" from Repositories
- Go to Settings - Tools - File Watchers
- Define a Webpack Task

  - File Types: Any
  - Define a new Scope to watch only your javascript files
  - Program: Either run webpack from /node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    or create some other executable file (like $ProjectFileDir$/webpack.sh)
  - If you choose to run webpack from node_modules (which btw didnt work for me because of relative path issues) insert Arguments (like --config)
  - Set output path to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/src/main/static/js/bundled
  - Set working directory to: $ProjectFileDir$

Now if you save a file in your defined scope the webpack task will run. After that you have to refresh the page in your browser. Got the idea from [https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000378264-Make-IntelliJ-automatically-detect-changes-produced-by-webpack)

---

2) 
This way is more advanced, but harder to configure correctly. You will have auto-reload (the page refreshes) and full hot reloading (the react state persists)

The basic idea is to run a webpack-dev-server and use that server as a reverse proxy for your spring-boot backend. The dev-server will handle requests to hot-reloaded content himself and pass everything else to your backend. Got the idea from [https://www.codingbismuth.com/](https://www.codingbismuth.com/spring-react-and-webpack-using-the-webpack-dev-server/) .

As a example configuration

```html
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "keywords": [
    "xy"
  ],
  "author": "murphy",
  "license": "",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev_server.js"
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^2.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.1.8",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-datetime": "^2.11.1",
    "rest": "^1.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "swagger-ui": "^3.13.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.15",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "eslint": "^4.13.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-watch": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.40.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin2": "^1.0.3"
  }
}
```

```html
const { resolve } = require('path');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: resolve(__dirname, '.'),

    entry: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        // activate HMR for React

        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8888',
        // bundle the client for webpack-dev-server
        // and connect to the provided endpoint

        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        // bundle the client for hot reloading
        // only- means to only hot reload for successful updates

        // the entry point of our app
        './src/main/js/router/mainrouter.jsx',
    ],
    output: {
        filename: './mainbundle.js',
        // the output bundle

        path: resolve(__dirname, '/src/main/resources/static/js/bundled'),

        publicPath: '/js/bundled/',
        // necessary for HMR to know where to load the hot update chunks
    },

    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        contentBase: [resolve(__dirname, "."), resolve(__dirname, "./src/main/resources/static/js/bundled")],
        proxy: {
            "/": {
                target: {
                    host: "localhost",
                    protocol: 'http:',
                    port: 8087,
                },
            },
            ignorePath: true,
            changeOrigin: true,
            secure: false,
        },
        publicPath: '/js/bundled/',
        port: 8888,
        host: "localhost",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "eslint-loader",
                options: {
                    // fix: true, // autofix
                    cache: true,
                    failOnError: false,
                    emitWarning: true,
                    quiet: true,
                },
            },
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    // cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?modules'],
            },
        ],
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        // enable HMR globally

        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        // prints more readable module names in the browser console on HMR updates
    ],
};
```

The spring boot app is running on :8087 and the webpack dev server on :8888. Now in your index.html you include the mainbundle.js.
Run your spring-boot app and in a second terminal run:

```
npm run start:dev
```

Access the webpage on :8888 to have hot reloading on file changes.

Comment: Thanks @murphy1312 for the detailed answer. I used step 1 as mentioned above and it has been immensely useful as I was wasting a lot of time repackaging the application. Not sure why your solution has not been accepted. It definitely works.

Comment: I am impressed with both the ways you came up with, 2nd one is a bit complex, 3rd way which I am using is : Use dev:watch of npm and create output in targer/classes/public folder and tell tomcat (as i use war archive) to update resource on frame deactivation... it take 3-5 second of time to update but reduces a lot of complixities for maintainance.

Answer (score 1):

For React you can install [Babel CLI](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-cli) with the [React Preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-preset-react), and run Babel in `--watch` mode. It will continuously transpile your JSX to JavaScript, and if you have Spring DevTools installed you'll see the new information immediately after reloading your web page when running in your IDE.

I've written up a full tutorial at [No-Fuss React and JSX with Spring Boot](https://www.garretwilson.com/blog/2023/03/21/no-fuss-react-jsx-with-spring-boot), but here's the gist of it:

```bash
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-react
npx babel src/main/resources/static --out-dir target/classes/static --presets=@babel/preset-react --only="**/*.jsx" --watch
```

My article goes into depth about how to integrate this transparently into the Maven build, and how to structure your HTML so that you won't need Webpack or any larger front-end build system other than Maven.